# The type org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.* is not visible

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I am trying to reimplement the AbstractTextEditor class but the problem that I couldn't add org.eclipse.ui.texteditor in dependencies section. Does it depend on other one?

[image: Dependencies page]

Comment: Don't confuse the name of plug-ins and the packages they contain, or just import the package using the list on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

The `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor` Java package containing `AbstractTextEditor` is in the `org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor` plug-in which you already have in your dependencies. You do not need to do anything else to the dependencies.

Although Java package names are often similar to the plug-in id that contains them this is not a required.

Also I see you have `org.eclipse.ui.editors.source` and `org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.source` in your dependencies - these are source code only plug-ins used internally by Eclipse you don't need them in the dependencies list. They may cause complications when you try and build the plug-in.

Comment: thank you i deleted the 2 unused dependencies. The errors such as `The type org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.SelectionListener is not visible` still persist.

Comment: That class is private to AbstractTextEditor you cannot use it. You probably have the wrong import - most likely you want `org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener`